# What are some useful invariants for distinguishing between random graph models?

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Quite a few probabilistic algorithms for generating random graphs exist in the literature, such as:

- The [Erdős-Rényi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model)
- The [Stochastic Block model](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00609)
- The [Watts-Strogatz model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model)
- The [Barabasi-Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model)

and many others. The general sort of question that I am trying to ask is: how do you do Bayesian statistics with random graphs?  In other words: what can you infer about the underlying random graph model by looking at data?  A natural strategy is to look at statistical properties of ordinary graph invariants, such as:

- The degree distribution
- The distribution of path lengths
- The [clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient)

These specific invariants are nice for statistics because they are relatively predictable for many graph models (e.g. it is known that degrees are asymptotically Poisson for Erdős-Rényi graphs and asymptotically power law for preferential attachment graphs) and they aren't too hard to compute from data.

> What are some other "nice for statistics" graph invariants?

I'm curious about spectral invariants in particular, though this might be no easier than the well-known hard problem of estimating eigenvalues of random matrices.

For this question let's assume that the graphs are undirected, simple, and large but finite.

Comment: Perhaps this should be CW?

Comment: I don't think this needs to be CW.

Answer (score 5):

Any property for which there is an efficient [property testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_testing) algorithm is a candidate, because such algorithms are extremely efficient.

Another approach is to note that many random graph models have an associated graphon, so (especially if you have a lot of samples of the graphs of interest) you could try to approximately compute the graphon.  This is computationally intensive but has the advantage that it will probably expose a lot of important properties all at once.  One relevant paper on this topic is [Airoldi et al.](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5047-stochastic-blockmodel-approximation-of-a-graphon-theory-and-consistent-estimation.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your applications/goals, and the graphs you consider.
Do you want to compare graph sequences or graphs of a fixed size?

First let's consider sequences.

The problem with property testing invariants is that they are trivial for any non-dense class of graphs (including the Watts-Strogatz and Barabasi-Albert models).
In other words, $\mathcal{G}_i \rightarrow W_0$ for any graph sequences with $o(n^2)$ edges, where $W_0$ is the empty graphon.

The close equivalent of such properties for sparse-graphs is the distribution of neighborhoods, which gives the framework of local weak convergence.
You can also look at the degree-degree correlations(Joint-Degree Distribution), or correlations for more vertices, but it becomes computationally expensive.

There are some invariants that work for any class of graph, such as the class of first-order definable properties, or connectivity, hamiltonicity, etc, but either they are a bit too simple (FO-properties) or they lack a proper way to be treated uniformly.

There are many other less known invariants, either in the social network community (Between-ness, Elite/Rich club or community analysis) or in the theoretical world (a good place to start is [1]). Here the keyword is "graph metrics".

If you are not interested in asymptotic analysis, you can pretty much use anything, including a mix of algorithms for sparse graphs and algorithms for dense graphs. With some applications in mind, you can also use the result/statistics of some algorithms as invariants (e.g. some routing algorithms). In that case rigorous mathematical may be out of the question, but it may be much more useful in practice [2][3].

[1] Bollobás, Riordan "Sparse graphs: metrics and random models."

[2] Sala, Cao, Wilson, Zablit, Zheng, "Measurement-calibrated graph models for social network experiments"

[3] Li, Alderson, Willinger, Doyle, "A first-principles approach to understanding the internet's router-level topology"